# WPF: Fire data trigger when the value of the string is null or string.Empty

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, datatrigger

I have created a `DataTemplate`

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Person}">
  <StackPanel>
    <!-- Text box is binding to the person's Image property. -->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Image}" />
    <Border>
      <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
          <Style.Triggers>
            <!-- Data trigger is binding to the same Image property. -->
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Image}" Value="{x:Null}">
              <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                  <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#696969" Offset="0.0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#2E2E2E" Offset="1.0" />
                  </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </Border.Style>
    </Border>
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

The `Person` class looks like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

The presented data trigger in the data template does not work as expected. No matter if I provide the value for the `Image` property or not, it simply won't draw the linear gradient brush background. On the other hand, the text block is showing the content of the `Image` property as it should.

I thought that maybe when the `person.Image = null;`, then the XAML is in fact reading it as  `person.Image = string.Empty;` but I tried replacing `Value="{x:Null}"` with `Value=""` and it still doesn't work.

Help please, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing Change Notification on your Person class. That might be the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The binding is correct, but you don't see anything because your `Border` is 0×0 px. You can get the desired effect like this:

```
<Border Width="50">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Image}" />
    <!-- your style unchanged -->
</Border>
```

Comment: I added border width and height properties. I even added the `Background="Red"` property, but red won't turn into linear gradient. Do you have any other suggestions perhaps?

Comment: That's odd, it works that way for me. Although only for `null`, not for an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

As AbdouMoumen has suggested, implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your Person class.

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _image;
    public string Image
    {
        get { return _image; }
        set
        {
            _image = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Image");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Then only setting person.Image = null will have effect on your xaml.